# non-interactive Python command history

Tags: python, command, backlog

I know the python interpreter and ipython have a easy way to browse through the history of commands. That is in interactive Python programming.

My problem/question:
I have a GUI-based Python tool that allows me to click and enter values in fields before hitting the "PLOT" button and I get a plot on screen. What I am looking for is a way to access a "minimimum script" that exactly reproduces the plot.

So I was wondering if there was a way to request a backlog of all the commands an uninteractive Python instance went through.

If it is not built-in, could someone advise a way to automatically dump function calls in a file at the same time as they are run.

Comment: an 'uninteractive python instance' is called a python program. It's python source code is the commands the 'instance' went through.

Comment: I agree Martijn. Maybe my choice of words was not the best. But note I have a GUI-based tool, and what I would like is a way to generate a (smaller) source code that only lists the function calls it went through, without all the clicking and editing...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do that would be to [Pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) your plot object. Then you can just reload the pickle file and the object will be in memory just as it was when dumped.

It should only take a couple of lines to implement a dump and reload feature in your program.

This of course doesn't give you a list of commands or anything like that to regenerate the figure, but it does give you the exact state of the object.

If you are using `matplotlib` to do the plotting, then the [image itself is not picklable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348733/saving-interactive-matplotlib-figures). But you could create a class that contains all the information you entered that is passed to the `matplotlib` routines and pickle that, again saving the state.

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of Pickles and the fact that matplotlib objects were not yet fully pickable. Thus the idea to create a "minimum script that can reproduce the graph". "Creating a class that contains all the information you entered" does not seem like a quick and easy (read quick and dirty) way of reaching my goal.

Comment: @user1866050 You may want to put more details in your question to indicate that you are using things like `matplotlib`. There's more than one way to generate a plot.