# Save figure parameters after interactive tweaking

Tags: python, matplotlib

I often find myself using matplotlib to quickly display data, then later going back and tweaking my plotting code to make pretty figures. In this process, I often use the interactive plot window to adjust things like spacing, zooming, cropping, etc. While I can easily save the resulting figure to an image file, what I really want is to save the sequence of function calls/parameters that produced it.

Note that I don't particularly care to open the same figure again (as in [Saving interactive Matplotlib figures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348733/saving-interactive-matplotlib-figures)). Even something as simple as being able to print the various properties of the figure and axes would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't have the answer to your specific question, I'd generally suggest using the [Ipython Notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html) for these things (and much more!)

Make sure you have `%pylab inline` in one cell.

When you plot, it will display it in the notebook itself. Then within your cell, just keep experimenting until you have it right (use `Ctrl-Enter` in the cell). Now the cell will have all the statements you need (and no more!)

The difference between the command line interpreter and the notebook is that the former *all* statements you typed which leads to a lot of clutter. With the notebook you can edit the line in place.

Answer (score 1):

A [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348733/saving-interactive-matplotlib-figures)
has an [answer I just posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348733/saving-interactive-matplotlib-figures/35100106#35100106).

The gist: use MatPlotLib's picklable figure object to save the figure object to a file.  See the aforementioned answer for a full example.
Here's a shortened example:

```
fig, ax = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots()
# plot some stuff

import pickle
pickle.dump(  fig,  open('SaveToFile.pickle',  'wb')  )
```

This does indeed save all plotting tweaks, even those made by the GUI subplot-adjuster.  Unpickling via `pickle.load()` still allows you to interact via CLI or GUI.