# Matplotlib save file to be reedited later in ipython

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib

Is there a way to save the 'state' of a matplotlib figure so that I may open up the plot and interact with it later, e.g. in a new ipython notebook session.

Plotting pdfs and other file formats doesn't quite do justice if you want to edit the figure later.

This would be useful if you want to annotate or rescale a figure later, but you don't necessarily have all the access to the original script/data that produced the figure.

In matlab, which ipython is often reported to try to emulate in many ways, you can simply save the file as a `.fig` or even a script, like `.m` (matlab) file! then you reopen your `.m` or `.fig` in a later matlab session and edit it.

Can this be done with matplotlib?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving interactive Matplotlib figures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348733/saving-interactive-matplotlib-figures)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pickle a figure to disk like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pickle

# Plot
fig_object = plt.figure()
x = np.linspace(0,3*np.pi)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
# Save to disk
pickle.dump(fig_object,file('sinus.pickle','w'))
```

And then load it from disk and display:

```
fig_object = pickle.load(open('sinus.pickle','rb'))
fig_object.show()
```

Comment: to be clear. what exactly is the fig_object. is that what you get when you do `fig_object= plt.plot(x,y)`

Comment: Uhmm... shouldn't `fig_object` be  a figure instance? `plot` returns a list and thus `fig_object.show()` will fail. Use `fig_object = plt.gcf()`.

Comment: Updated my answer so it has more details about fig_object

Comment: The saving to disk part should probably look more like `pickle.dump(fig_object, open('sinus.pickle','wb'))`. Can't suggest an edit due to `Suggested edit queue is full`.

Comment: I can confirm that the correct command is "pickle.dump(fig_object, open('sinus.pickle','wb'))"