# saving and then opening interactive 3d matplotlib figures

Tags: matplotlib, interactive

I am generating 3D interactive matplotlib figures.I would like to save them and then open them and still have the interactive capability.

1.How can I do this? Right now when I save them all the interactive features are lost.

2.Is there a workaround? for example save in a '.fig' format from python and then open it in matlab? or use a python to matlab connector?

Comment: Figure serialization is on the near-term todo list.  You _can_ but shouldn't use pickles for this purpose.  It is best to write your self a function that does all of your plotting and then just re-call that function with data when you want to recreate the figure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [saving interactive matplotlib figures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348733/saving-interactive-matplotlib-figures)