# Why must you pickle Matplotlib figure before saving to file, not vice versa?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, pickle

I've noticed that I cannot pickle a matplotlib figure after saving it as an image, whether as png, jpeg, or pdf. Why is this the case? Is there a clean way around this if a workflow calls for saving as png, then later as a pickle?
I'm using matplotlib version 1.3.1, which is the default on a new Mac OS presently (early 2016).

A simple working example is below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle
import numpy as np

eigval = np.random.rand(10)
nbins = 15
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10*0.6, 5*0.6))
hist_vals = np.array([np.abs(np.imag(eigval[i])) for i in range(len(eigval))])
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(hist_vals, nbins)

plt.savefig('./test.png')
pickle.dump(fig, file('./test.pkl','w'))
```

This returns

```
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <built-in method copy_from_bbox of tuple object at 0x10bc1f998>: it's not found as __main__.copy_from_bbox
```

If instead we output to pdf first, we get

```
TypeError: can't pickle instancemethod objects
```

And for jpg, we get

```
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type '_macosx.GraphicsContext'>: it's not found as _macosx.GraphicsContext
```

Thanks!

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: Thanks, I updated the question.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35100106/2308683

Comment: Also related-- this was my guide to thinking this should work: http://fredborg-braedstrup.dk/blog/2014/10/10/saving-mpl-figures-using-pickle/
Thanks @cricket_007

Comment: Your example worked fine for me. I'm using MatPlotLib 1.5.0. Since pickling was only introduced in 1.2.0 it may be that the 1.3.1 version was still a bit buggy. Can't you upgrade to the latest version?

Comment: Thanks @titusjan, glad this is fixed. I think I may experience some compatibility issues with a particular package upon upgrading, but I should probably bite that bullet and be current, even if it means spending a day fixing things.