# Matplotlib: Saving the image generated, so as to zoom and do other activity

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am using the matplotlib to plot a graph.
The code snippet is as below.

```
        err_df = inp_err.as_data_frame()
        err_df['id']=err_df.index
        print(err_df.iloc[200:220])
        err_df.plot(kind='scatter',x='id',y='Reconstruction.MSE',figsize=(20,6))
        plt.show()
```

it opens image in this matplotlib viewer. where i am easily able to zoom in and out and do other actions present in the above toolbar,

[image]

but the issue is, once I save this image
then I get only  a screen shot sort-of, of the image and I can't do zoom in zoom out and other actions, the way I was able to do in the matplotlib editor. 
Is there any way to open matplot editor from outside the code and then in which format should I save the image. Or any other way to perform the same operations like zoom as matplotlib editor with some other editor.

TIA

Comment: You can specify a location while saving as plt.savefig(‘/Users/Bazingaa/Desktop/image.png’) for rxample

Comment: Problem is once is save it as png it will be a static image. will not be able to zoom in to see more details.. the zoom will just make the image big

Comment: This topic is discussed in [Saving interactive Matplotlib figures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348733/saving-interactive-matplotlib-figures)