# Can't pickle or dill FigureCanvasQTAgg

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pickle, dill

I am trying to dump a figure object into a pickle file and it keeps failing using Python 3.7.1.

```
#python.version = 3.7.3
#pickle.format_version = '4.0'
#dill.__version__ = '0.2.9'
print(ax, type(ax))
print(matplotlib.get_backend())
print(matplotlib.__version__)
print(sys.version_info)
with open("MyFile", "wb") as dill_file:
    dill.dump(ax, dill_file)
pt.savefig("MyFile_"+now)
```

The results are:

```
AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.35) 
<class'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>
Qt5Agg
3.0.2
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=7, micro=1, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

Then the error:

> >
>   error from callback : can't pickle FigureCanvasQTAgg objects

The above code is not in a class. I have tried other backends (Agg, TkAgg, etc) with same result. I have also tried using just `pickle.dump` with same results.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. This runs fine for me on python 3.6.6, mpl 3.0.2.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I am using python 3.7.1, I updated my question.

Comment: Yeah, but the python version is pretty irrelevant. I just tested and it works with 3.7.1 as well.

Comment: Bummer. For now I just save data to csv then recall it with a program that plots it... which has a benefit of being a smaller memory footprint.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this, according to [Saving interactive Matplotlib figures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348733/saving-interactive-matplotlib-figures)

... but this is exprimental and has downsides. Consider saving to .SVG file as that answer says.